# How to perform unit tests with h2 database where bpchar is used?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, testing, h2

I have a spring + hibernate application that uses postgres database. I need to write unit tests for the controllers. For tests I wanted to use h2 database but unfortunately test crashes during create-drop leaving me with information that bpchar data type is invalid. I wonder how to solve this issue so I could run tests.

I can't change my columns with bpchar to varchar, it need to stay as it is. I also tried to set postgresql mode but it didn't helped. 
Am I right that the only solution I have is to use embedded postgres database in order to perform tests or is there any other approach that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that the only solution I have is to use embedded postgres database in order to perform tests or is there any other approach that I could use?

You try to use postgres-specific data type with h2 (which does not have it). Of course, it does not work.

If you cannot change type of this field - use embedded postgres in tests.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do this in your *application.properties* to let H2 know:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE TYPE BPCHAR AS CHARACTER NOT NULL
```

Also make sure auto configuration of the database is turned off for your test. You can do this by adding:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MyTestForTableWithBpcharColumn {
```

Answer (score 0):

One interesting approach to this issue is [Test Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)

Since Postgres doesn't have an embedded mode, but you can use the aforementioned framework to start the docker container before the test, create a schema and apply migrations if you're using something like Flyway or Liquibase or integrate your custom solution.

The idea is that the container will be prepared and available to the test when it runs.
After the test passes (regardless of the actual result, success or failure) you can stop the container.

Firing up the container can be quite expensive (a matter of seconds), however you can take advantage of spring caching configurations during the tests, so when the first test in the module starts, the container is actually started, however, it gets reused between the tests and the test cases, since the application context doesn't get re-started.

Keeping the database clean between tests also becomes a trivial task due to Spring's `@Transactional` annotation that you put on a test case, so that spring artificially rolls back the transaction after each test. Since in Postgres, even DDL commands can be transactional it should be good enough.

The only limitation of this approach is that you should have a docker available on build machine or local development machine if you're planning to run these tests locally (on Linux and Mac OS its not a problem anyway, but on Windows you need to have Windows 10 Professional edition at least in order to be able to install docker environment).

I've used this approach in real projects and found it very effective for integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but it did not work.  Then I found a new fix as below and it worked. Changed the following in application.properties for the unit test resource

```
//Common properties for using the H2 database
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Added a new file under resources for the test folder named "schema.sql" with the following content
`CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS bpchar as varchar;`

The entity class annotation looks like this to me

`@Column(name = "XXXXX", length = 1, columnDefinition = "bpchar")`

These 2 changes worked for me.