# How to set annotation attribute value based on the active profile in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I use two mirror database schemas in my Spring Boot application with Flyway migration on startup: an in-memory **H2** - for `demo` profile, and **Postgres** - for `prod`. In each schema, there is a `reset_token` field which is defined like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users( 
    ... 
    reset_token CHAR(36)
);
```

The problem is that Hibernate expects two different annotations to be used for correct mapping of String property in my `User` entity into corresponding table column: `@Column(columnDefinition = "char")` - for **H2** and `@Column(columnDefinition = "bpchar")` - for **Postgres**. How can I do that? I mean, is it possible to set the value of `columnDefinition` attribute, based on the active profile, so that not to create two different `User` entities for each profile?

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @Column(columnDefinition = "char")
    // @Column(columnDefinition = "bpchar")
    private final String resetToken;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try sticking to `@Column(columnDefinition = "bpchar")` and appending `;MODE=PostgreSQL` to the H2 JDBC connection string.

If that doesn't work, perhaps [this answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787002/1092818).

If *that* doesn't work either, then I'd suggest the answer just below it.

Comment: Actually, I've already switched to replacing `CHAR` with `VARCHAR` which doesn't entail any discrepancy between different RDBMS and actually doesn't need `@Column` annotation at all for correct mapping. But thank you anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need columnDefinition, just use @Column

Comment: No. It's not working. *org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [reset_token] in table [users]; found [char (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)*

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you at all

Answer (score 0):

In the annotation you can use final var. So you will need to add a final variable that will hold your tokenType. This var will be populated from the active profile.
You can use something like this:

```
@Value("${tokenType}") // will take the value from active profile
private final String tokenType = "char";

@Column(columnDefinition = tokenType)
private final String resetToken;
```

Comment: Unfortunately `@Value` is not working with `final` variable, so `tokenType` preserves its `"char"` value as soon as it's been initialized and doesn't want to change it.

Comment: than remove  = "char"

Comment: If I remove "char" and leave tokenType unassigned, then @Column won't compile saying "Attribute value must be constant".